# GTM - load js file src - doesn't run

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a js script I want to load on certain pages with GTM.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/assets/js/example.js"></script>
```

In GTM I have created a custom html tag and inserted the above.  For the trigger I have tried them all... initialization, page view, dom ready, etc... no matter which trigger I use, after publishing, the code in my js file never runs (I'm putting a console.log('test') at the top to test that).  I do see the script added to the dom of the page though.

The script :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
   console.log('test');
   ... rest of code here
});
```

Even commenting out the load listener so just my code is there does not change anything.

Yes, the script works without errors.  If I manually add the script tag to any of the pages it works as should error free.

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 1):

Preview your workspace in GTM preview, make sure the tag actually fires.

Or check if it actually adds the script to the DOM, that would probably be faster.

Then check the network tab, make sure the script loads with no issues.

Then try getting rid of the event listener in the script and just execute the console log. You already deploying the script on the load, **why adding another listener to the load**? That's probably your issue. Setting the onload listener after the load event.

I'll keep the proper debugging steps for the future reference.

Comment: If you read my original post the script does get added to the DOM and I have tried it with and without the load listener - doesn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe the browser cached it while you had the listener in? And what about the network?

Comment: Ended up being a caching issue... I typically do a ctrl-f5 to force new version of files, but I suspect since the js script tag is being 'added' by GTM that didn't do the trick.  I ended up opening the file itself in a new tab, then doing ctrl-f5, which got the latest version... then I could go back to the site and it would use the latest.